# Signal Filter with Rx.NET

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'd like to implement a signal filter in Rx.NET which starts with an initial set of coefficients. As time goes by the filter coefficients have to be recalculated from a snapshot of observed data values.

Here is a small prototype which shows how it should work. For simplicity I choose the filter length and the number of the historical data values used to recalculate the filter coefficients to be the same (3 in the example).

The example uses a side effect in `bufferedAt10` to recalculate the coefficients. This is not what I would like to have.

In the real application the data is coming in irregular time steps and the coefficient should be updated once a day or once a week at a specific time. I can easily make the buffer longer, but how can I let the system run and change the filter coefficients from a observer in a clean functional way?

```
       // create a hot obvervable to produce data
        const int bufLen = 3;
        var rng = new Random();
        var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        var observable = Observable.Interval(period)
        .Select(i => new {Time = DateTime.Now, Price = rng.NextDouble()})
        .Do(e => Console.WriteLine("original : {0}", e))
        .Publish();
        observable.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to subscribe");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // buffer of length bufLen used for filter calculation (every tick) and filter 
        // coefficient update (at a lower frequency)
        var buffered = observable.Buffer(bufLen, 1);

        // apply the signal filter with coefficients in `coeff`
        var coeff = new List<Double>() {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};  // these will be updated on the way from new data 
        var filtered = buffered.Select(e =>
        {
            var f = 0.0;
            for (var i = 0; i < bufLen; i++)
            {
                f += e[i].Price*coeff[i]; // apply the filter with coefficients `coeff`
            }
            return new {Time = DateTime.Now, FilteredPrice = f};
        });

        var s1 = filtered.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine("filtered : {0} (coeff {1},{2},{3})", e, coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2]));

        // recalculate the filter coefficients say every 10 seconds 
        var bufferedAt10 = buffered.DistinctUntilChanged(e => (e[bufLen - 1].Time.TimeOfDay.Seconds / 10) * 10);

        var s2 = bufferedAt10.Subscribe(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("recalc of coeff : {0}", e[bufLen - 1].Time);
            for (var i = 0; i < bufLen; i++)
            {
                // a prototypical function that takes the buffer and uses it to "recalibrate" the filter coefficients
                coeff[i] = coeff[i] + e[bufLen - 1 - i].Price;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("updated coeffs to {0},{1},{2}", coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2]);
        });
```

Thanks for any good advice.

Answer (score 1):

The following is untested but I think it should cover what you need. The idea behind it is that you diverge the streams do the coefficient updates on one, and then bring them back together with `WithLatestFrom`. I used `Sample` and `Scan` to perform the period "adjustment". And your custom timestamping can be done by using the `TimeStamp` operator instead. You may also consider moving the `Publish` down past `Buffer` otherwise you will have two streams generating buffers, but it is up to you.

```
const int bufLen = 3;
var rng = new Random();
var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
var observable = Observable.Interval(period)
  .Select( => rng.NextDouble())
  .Publish();
observable.Connect();

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to subscribe");
Console.ReadKey();

var buffered = observable.Buffer(bufLen, 1);

var seed = new [] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

var coefficients = buffered
                     //Samples for a new value every 10 seconds
                     .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                     //Updates the seed value and emits it after every update
                     .Scan(seed, 
                       //Use good old fashion Linq
                       (coeff, delta) => coeff.Zip(delta.Reverse(), 
                                         (c, d) => c + d.Price)
                                         .ToArray()
                       );

//Emits a new value everytime buffer emits, and combines it with the latest
//values from the coefficients Observable
//Kick off coefficients with the seed otherwise you need to wait 10 seconds 
//for the first value.
buffer.WithLatestFrom(coefficients.StartWith(seed), (e, coeff) => {
  return e.Zip(coeff, (x, c) => x.Price * c).Sum();
})
.TimeStamp()
.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine("filtered : {0}", e);
```

Comment: Many thanks, I get the idea. I guess `WithLatestFrom` should be `CombineLatest`.

Comment: @Daniel `CombineLatest` will trigger if *either* of the source Observables emit. `WithLatestFrom` will trigger only if the first source emits. It may only be available in the pre-release version 2.3.0-beta